# CSV file having chinese content shows unknown characters

Tags: c++, excel, iostream, cout

My project generates report in CSV format based on selected language. We supports 17 languages in that Asian languages like Chinese/Japanese and Korean not working. Contents inside shows some unknow character but on opening same in Notepad++ and excel by choosing unicode "65001: Unicode (UTF-8)" its showing Chinese character properly.

In code we set some flags while generating CSV

```
std::ofstream* outFile = new std::ofstream(qPrintable(filePath),std::ios::app);
CSVostream csv( outFile );
csv.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
```

Do we need to set some other flag or what I am missing I am not sure. Can some one provide some light on this.

Comment: what is `CSVostream` ?

Comment: Its a middle level class which inturn calls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xiosbase"

Comment: CSVostream( std::ostream* out, std::string separator = "," );

Comment: where do you see the unexpected characters? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Unexpected characters in generated CSV file. I want to know do we need to set some flags for Chinese language in OSTREAM

Comment: How do you know there are unexpected characters in the CSV file?

Comment: CSV generated and while opening in EXcel it shows like this "æŽ¢å¤´éƒ¨ä»¶å·:"

Comment: When I open the same file in Notepad++ it shows expected chinese character

Comment: You said that excel loaded the file correctly when you told it that it was utf-8? I don't see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in how the file is *written* but how it is *read*.

CSV files are text files and they carry no meta-information on how they are encoded. So it's up the user to guess. In your case, Notepad++ seems to be better at guessing than Excel.

A similar problem was asked in [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Some answers mention adding a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the CSV which is recognized by some versions of Excel.

Some more related questions:

[Opening CSV with UTF-8 BOM via Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275470/opening-csv-with-utf-8-bom-via-excel)

[Should UTF-8 CSV files contain a BOM byte order mark (on SE SE)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372692/should-utf-8-csv-files-contain-a-bom-byte-order-mark)